# Pass events to UITableViewCell outside of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer

I have an app that shows a list of podcasts episodes on a `UITableView`. Each cell is managed with a custom class extending `UITableViewCell` and each cell has it's own instance of `AVAudioPlayer` to control the playback of the episode. What I am trying to do is the next:

When I click play on an episode, if there is another episode playing, then stop it, and start the new one.

What I did to achieve this was to create a protocol on the `UITableViewCell` that fires an event whenever the play button is pressed. Then implemented that protocol on my `UIViewController` and get the latest selected cell with `cellForRowAt` (I keep a reference of the latest selected `IndexPath`) and the call the pause method. That seemed to work but then I realized that it only works if both cells are visible on the screen. Whenever I want to get a cell with `cellForRowAt` that is not in the screen, the method returns null and I can't update the cell, which lead to having two cells playing sound at the same time.

Here's my code for the cell:

```
@IBAction func playbackButtonHandler(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let audioPlayer = self.player else {
        self.downloadAudio(forPodcast: podcast.id)
        return
    }
    guard let cellIndex = indexPath else { return }
    if (audioPlayer.isPlaying) {
        audioPlayer.pause()
        delegate?.onPauseActionSelected(forRow: cellIndex)
    } else {
        audioPlayer.play()
        delegate?.onPlayActionSelected(forRow: cellIndex)
    }
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

and the ViewController:

```
func onPlayActionSelected(forRow row: IndexPath) {
    if let activeItem = self.activePodcast {
        if row != activeItem {
            guard let activeCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: activeItem) as? PodcastCell else { return }
            activeCell.playbackButtonHandler(activeCell.playbackButton)
        }
    }
    self.activePodcast = row
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Tried Larme's suggestions and created a singleton in the ViewController for the `AVAudioController` that took care of the problem of two audio tracks playing at the same time. However, that still leaves the question how to update the controls of the cells because the pause button is still visible as if it was still playing audio.
See images for clarification:

I have a cell that is not in the screen anymore playing audio. Then I click play on the first cell. Audios stop and starts playing on the first cell

[image: I have a cell that is not in the screen anymore playing audio. Then I click play on the first cell. Audios stops and starts playing on the first cell]

Now I scroll to the bottom and although the cell is not playing anymore, the pause button is still visible. I need a way to call the cell to change that button's state

[image: Now I scroll to the bottom and although the cell is not playing anymore, the pause button is still visible. I need a way to call the cell to change that button's state]

Comment: Please don't ask "bonus questions". Keep each post to a single issue. Post an additional question if you have another issue.

Comment: Indeed `cellForRow(at:)` returns nil if the cell is not visible. What I'd do is to use only one player (in ViewController, a Singleton?), edit the object of your array (that you can retrieve with the `indexPath`) keeping "isPlaying", "currentProgression" (for being able to do a "playAtTime"), etc.

Comment: @Larme I tried that but it still leaves me with the problem of updating the cell that is not visible. I updated my question with some images to illustrate the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one among the 2 issues is fixed, that is playing 2 audios at the same time. Now the second issue, that is refreshing the UI. You should show the pause button in the cell which is playing the audio, whereas play button will replace the pause button in the last played cell.

Now you don't need to call cellForRow in **onPlayActionSelected** method. Instead write the code in the cellForRowAt delegate method of your tableview. Because you don't need to change the pause button of previous cell instantly if that cell is not visible, only when the user scrolls down to the position, you need to change the pause button to play button, so the user wont see the difference.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let activeCell = /* Deque your tableViewCell with its subclass */

    if let activeItem = self.activePodcast {
        if indexPath.row == activeItem {
            activeCell.buttonImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Play")!
        }else  {
            activeCell.buttonImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Pause")!
        }
    }

    return activeCell
}
```